# java operator `+` and `StringBuilder.append`

Tags: java, decompiler

It was said that when I use `+` operator to concat `String` it later transforms into `StringBuilder.append` but when I ran Java Decompiler GUI and opened `MainClass.class` there was

```
public class MainClass
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    String str1 = "abc";
    String str2 = "def";

    String str3 = str1 + str2;
  }
}
```

when the original was

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String val1 = "abc";
        String val2 = "def";

        String res = val1 + val2;

    }
}
```

What is wrong?
I compiled it using `javac MainClass.java`

Comment: Use `javap -v MainClass` you will get to know that `StringBuilder` is being used. Also, a *decompiler* decompiles the code and tries to give the original source code (reverse operation of the compiler). You need to check the `class` file.

Comment: I see. There is a line with `stringbuilder.append`. But why java decompiler does not show in `.class` file that line? I thought it should be change in `.class` file.

Comment: Please see what a decompiler is.

Comment: I get it. Are there tools where I can look through `compiled` but not `decompiled` code? I mean where I can see `stringbuilder.append`. Or is it not possible?

Comment: Like I said, use `javap -v ClassName`. And check the [byte code instruction listing here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

Comment: Since string concatenation is equivalent to the `StringBuilder` sequence generated by the compiler, many decompilers will simply reverse the transformation to provide what the decompiler author feels is the more concise/readable form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most decompilers will automatically transform the compiler generated `StringBuilder` sequences back into string concatenation with `+`.

One of the few that doesn't is [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau). If you decompile the class with Krakatau, you'll get something like

```
public class MainClass {
    public MainClass()
    {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        new StringBuilder().append("abc").append("def").toString();
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the `StringBuilder` code is there. You can also look at the disassembly to be sure.

```
.version 51 0
.source MainClass.java
.class super public MainClass
.super java/lang/Object


.method public <init> : ()V
    ; method code size: 5 bytes
    .limit stack 1
    .limit locals 1
    aload_0
    invokespecial java/lang/Object <init> ()V
    return
.end method

.method static public main : ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ; method code size: 26 bytes
    .limit stack 2
    .limit locals 4
    ldc 'abc'
    astore_1
    ldc 'def'
    astore_2
    new java/lang/StringBuilder
    dup
    invokespecial java/lang/StringBuilder <init> ()V
    aload_1
    invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    aload_2
    invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    invokevirtual java/lang/StringBuilder toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
    astore_3
    return
.end method
```